# Fullcalendar: on recurring events I don't want to display certain dates

Tags: fullcalendar, recurring-events

I am using fullcalendar as a booking agenda. I use recurring events to display the regulare availability of doctors.

It happens though that a doctor might not be available just for a certain date:

Example: Dr Smith works every monday from 1000 to 1800, but only next monday won't be available.

Recurring events in fullcalendar allows to show events in a specific date range.
But how can it be done the opposite (always show except within specific date range)?

Does any of you had this issue already?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/duu0dx2t/415/

Answer (score 0):

I have managed with a function using @Ryan89 JSFiddle.

```
//$val is doctor ID value
//adding not availabilty to repeating events
$adesso=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql_ecc="SELECT * FROM lpap_eccezioni_oneoff WHERE IDmedico=$val AND      datafine>'$adesso' AND stato='Non disponibile' ORDER BY datainizio";
$res_ecc=$wpdb->get_results($sql_ecc);
$qta=count($res_ecc);
if ($qta>0){
$eccezioni_non_disponibile=",ranges: [{start: moment().startOf('year'),";
foreach ($res_ecc as $val_ecc){
$stato=$val_ecc->stato;
if ($stato=="Disponibile"){$dispchecked="checked";$nondispchecked="";}
if ($stato=="Non disponibile"){$dispchecked="";$nondispchecked="checked";}

$datainizioecc=$val_ecc->datainizio;
$datafineecc=$val_ecc->datafine;
$IDeccezioni=$val_ecc->IDeccezioni;
$eccezioni_non_disponibile.="
end: moment('$datainizioecc','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'),
},{
start: moment('$datafineecc','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'),";           
}   
$eccezioni_non_disponibile.="end: moment('$datafineecc','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss').endOf('year'),
}]";
} else {$eccezioni_non_disponibile="";}
```

in order to get this code:

```js
 ranges: [{
     start: moment().startOf('year'), 
     end: moment('2016-06-13 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'),
    },{
     start: moment('2016-06-13 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'), 
     end: moment('2016-06-20 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'),
    },
        {
     start: moment('2016-06-20 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss'), 
     end: moment('2016-06-20 18:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss').endOf('year'),
    },]
```

I have added then on repeating events the $eccezioni_non_disponibile variable.
    $show_time.="{
    id: 'Disp_$val', resourceId: '$gruppo',
    title: '$cognome $nome - Presente',
    start: '$ora01',
    end: '$ora02',
    dow: [$key],
    color: '$rgba',
    borderColor: '$colore'
    $eccezioni_non_disponibile
    },";
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have asked Arshaw (fullcalendar' author) why JSfiddle works and not in my site and it looks that he doesn't know of any RANGES feature.

Have a look here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/189#event-689788358)